# Bromine test fails in alkene

Tags: organic-chemistry

My book ( OP Tondon - an indian author) mentions that Bromine-Carbon tetrachloride test fails for alkenes of the type C2R4(R is an alkyl substituent and the double bond is between the carbons). Is this true ? If yes, then why ? Shouldn't all alkenes change the colour of bromine ?

Comment: Is this an error on part of the author ?

Comment: Steric hindrance might come in, but the R groups would likely have to be large. 2,3-dimethyl-but-2-ene should react.

Comment: @OscarLanzi  I agree. This paper records that 2,3-dimethylbut-2-ene can be dibrominated with NDBA so hindrance is not a bar to its formation  https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1989/p1/p19890001381/unauth

Comment: Hax anybody tried this test on $\ce{C2R4}$ with $\ce{R = C(CH3)3}$ (or $ tert$-butyl) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Oscar Lanzi correctly pointed out the predominance of steric effects on the reactivity of tetrasubstituted alkenes $(\ce{R1R2C=CR3R4})$ is evident, which is confirmed by the careful work by Grosjean, *et al.* in 1976 (Ref.1). They concluded that it is likely that for the bromination of tetrasubstituted alkenes, the importance of steric effects indicates a clear predominance of bromine-substituent interactions in the rate-determining step, which is the formation of bromonium ion intermediate (Ref.1).

As expected, bromination of tetrasubstituted alkenes $(\ce{R1R2C=CR3R4})$ where R groups would be the smallest (2,3-dimethyl-but-2-ene, $\ce{Me2C=CMe2}$) is evident, considering the experimental rate constant of the reaction at $\pu {25 ^\circ C}$ in methanol is $\pu{9.16\times 10^5 M-1 s-1}$ (Ref.1). It is also have evidence that the structure of alkene and solvent play a significant role in this reaction (Ref.2). For example, when one of the $\ce{Me}$ group in $\ce{Me2C=CMe2}$ has been changed to a $\ce{Et}$ group, the bromination reaction rate of $\ce{Me2C=CMeEt}$ (2,3-dimethyl-pent-2-ene) have changed to $\pu{6.5\times 10^5 M-1 s-1}$ under similar condition (Ref.1). Further, it is evident that the bromination of alkenes under much extreme steric hindrence has still been possible. For instance, when all of the $\ce{Me}$ groups in $\ce{Me2=CMe2}$ has been changed to more bulkier groups such as $\ce{Et}$ and $\ce{n-Pr}$ groups, the bromination reaction has still been progressed. For example, the rate of $\ce{Et2C=CEt(n-Pr)}$ (3,4-diethyl-hept-3-ene) have changed to $\pu{1.43\times 10^4 M-1 s-1}$ under identical conditions (Ref.1). Thus, it is safe to say that under much more extreme steric effect, the bromination would still be processed. Note that the experimental rate for the bromination of $\ce{Me2C=CMe(neo-Pe)}$ (2,3,5,5-tetramethyl-hex-2-ene) has to be found as $\pu{1.78\times 10^3 M-1 s-1}$ under identical conditions (Ref.1). Therefore, it is safe to say that the statement of OP's book, *bromine test fails for tetra substituted-alkenes*, is errornous.

---

**References:**

1. Daniel Grosjean, Gerard Mouvier, and Jacques E. Dubois, "Bromination of ethylenic compounds. 39. Predominance of steric effects on the reactivity of tetrasubstituted alkenes," *J. Org. Chem.* **1976**, *41(24)*, 3872–3876 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00886a022).
2. Giorgio Modena, Franco Rivetti, and Umberto Tonellato, "Solvent and structure effects on the rates of bromine addition to acetylene derivatives. Analogies and differences in electrophilic additions to double and triple bonds," *J. Org. Chem.* **1978**, *43(8)*, 1521–1526 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00402a007).

Comment: Not convinced by Mathew's argument. Using his own data, if one methyl group from $\ce{Me2C=CMe2}$ is replaced by a neopentyl group, the rate constant decreases from $\ce{9.16·10^5 M^{-1} s^{-1}}$ to $\ce{1.78·10^3 M^{−1} s^{−1}}$ So it is about $500$ times less. And this happens when only one methyl group is substituted by a cumbersome group. What will happen if all four methyl groups are replaced by cumbersome radicals like $neo$-pentyl or $tert$-butyl ?

Comment: First of all, those data is not my own. They are fron the Refrence 1 I sighted correctly. Second, I'd likr to see an example of an alkene compond containing tetra neo-pentyl groups. ^Third, I didn't claim all of tetra-substituted alkenes undergoes bromination reaction, but  most of them gives positive test, even by some with highly steric hindrence such as specific alkene of interest.